# Is it possible to get the current gps position instantly ? android

Tags: android, gps, location

First, I have found the following solutions (which are not what I need)
         -Getting the last known position.
         -Adding a locationListener to get the current location.
But what I'm actually looking for is that : once the user opens my app, if the gps is enabled, I get his current position, is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Simply, no those are your only 2 options to get a location

Comment: Additionally you could persist the last location you know of, and use that while waiting for a new one..But with those 3 things combined, that's as good as it gets.

Comment: oh the problem is that once the user opens the app, he will have a form and he may submit it before getting the new position, I think that I will do as you said @DavidMedenjak. Thank you for your answers

Comment: let them fill out the form and disable its submission until location can be determined.

Comment: @petey great idea! just one little question, is there a case where that can take forever? ^^'

Comment: Without going to for last known location, yes.  Consider what might happen if GPS/Location Services is off. Or if user is in a tunnel. Try to display that location is required for this form to the user so that they know how to move past.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm thinking about waiting x secondes before taking the last known location, how much time should I wait ? is 1-2 secondes enough?